# Compare 2 lists and spot differences in google apps script

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, comparison

I am trying to compare 2 lists and get the value difference between them

```
list1 = [01-0161045, 01-0161046, 01-0158587, 01-0158647, 01-0158262, 01-0158264]
list2 = [01-0161045, 01-0161046, 01-0158587, 01-0158647, 01-0158262, 01-0158263,  01-0158265]
```

In the above 2 lists, first I need to compare list2 with list1 and differences are "01-0158263" and "01-0158265". This difference needs to be spitted to
a different list (say list3)

```
list3 = [01-0158263,  01-0158265]
```

Next, I compare list1 with list2 and difference is "01-0158264". This value needs to be appended to end of list2. We can save the results to list4.

```
list4 = [01-0161045, 01-0161046, 01-0158587, 01-0158647, 01-0158262, 01-0158263,  01-0158265, 01-0158264].
```

I have tried doing it using 2 for loops in Google Apps Script but it takes a long time when the list grows. Just wondering is there a way to do it efficiently using list comparison.

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal, how about the following sample script? In this sample script, 2 objects are created from `list2` and `list3`. And, using these objects, `list3` and `list4` are created.

#### Sample script:

```js
const list1 = ["01-0161045", "01-0161046", "01-0158587", "01-0158647", "01-0158262", "01-0158264"];
const list2 = ["01-0161045", "01-0161046", "01-0158587", "01-0158647", "01-0158262", "01-0158263", "01-0158265"];

const obj1 = list1.reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e]: true}), {});
const obj2 = list2.reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e]: true}), {});

const list3 = list2.filter(e => !obj1[e]);
const list4 = list2.concat(list1.filter(e => !obj2[e]));

console.log(list3)
console.log(list4)
```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Benchmark: Process Costs under V8 using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/7198bc9019202f4080de8fd2e1b278fb#6-only-reduce-objectassign-and-spread-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't use `filter()` with `includes()`?

```js
var list1 = ["01-0161045", "01-0161046", "01-0158587", "01-0158647", "01-0158262", "01-0158264"]
var list2 = ["01-0161045", "01-0161046", "01-0158587", "01-0158647", "01-0158262", "01-0158263",  "01-0158265"]

var list3 = list2.filter(x => !list1.includes(x));
var list4 = list2.concat(list1.filter(x => !list2.includes(x)));

console.log(list3);
console.log(list4);
```

I don't know if it's much better in terms of performance, though.