# Ascending sort in Google Apps Script

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script

I have a list in the below format

```
[[, 121, , 24603.0, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019, sunday, ], 
 [*, 131, , 62531.0, Sat Jul 13 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019, monday, ], 
 [*, 141, , 33210.0, Thu Jul 11 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019, tuesday, ], 
 [, 142, , -, , , Yes],
 [*, 143, , , Sat Jul 13 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019, monday, ]]
```

I am trying to sort the above list based on date column (5th column). Result has to be

```
[
 [*, 141, , 33210.0, Thu Jul 11 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019, tuesday, ], 
 [, 121, , 24603.0, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019, sunday, ], 
 [*, 131, , 62531.0, Sat Jul 13 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019, monday, ], 
 [*, 143, , , Sat Jul 13 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019, monday, ]]
 [, 142, , -, , , Yes]
]
```

Tried the below code but it does not work:

```
row.sort({column: 4, ascending: True});
```

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the third post today  repeating the same syntax problem with dates in JavaScript / Google Apps Script.  Previous posts were deleted instead of edited https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439932/compare-the-dates-in-different-lists-and-add-an-indicator, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67440109/using-dates-compare-2-lists-in-google-apps-script

Comment: @Rubén: Sorry nothing wrong, I was able to figure it out, that's why deleted it

Comment: If you figured it out why are you repeating the same syntax error from the first post again and again?

Comment: Actually very similar syntax errors are present at least on one question that has an accepted answer : https://stackoverflow.com/q/67384347/1595451

Comment: The code you quote suggests a misconception between JavaScript functions and spreadsheet formulas. See [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: Did you get correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {

  var arr = [
    ["",  121, "", "24603.0", "Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019", "sunday"  ], 
    ["*", 131, "", "62531.0", "Sat Jul 13 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019", "monday"  ], 
    ["*", 141, "", "33210.0", "Thu Jul 11 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019", "tuesday" ], 
    ["",  142, "", "-",       "",                                 , "Yes"     ],
    ["*", 143, "", "",        "Sat Jul 13 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019", "monday"  ]
  ]

  function compare_dates(date1, date2) {
    if (!date2) return -1;
    const d1 = new Date(date1);
    const d2 = new Date(date2);
    return d1 - d2;
  }

  var sorted_arr = arr.sort((a, b) => compare_dates(a[4], b[4]));

  Logger.log(sorted_arr.join("\n"));
}
```

The output looks almost as you want:

```
*, 141, , 33210.0, Thu Jul 11 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019, tuesday
,  121, , 24603.0, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019, sunday
*, 143, ,        , Sat Jul 13 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019, monday
*, 131, , 62531.0, Sat Jul 13 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019, monday
,  142, , -, , , Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In order to force the undefined to the bottom I force it to have an extremely large number so that sort ascending will always result in having the undefined values at the bottom of the list but in general it's probably not a good idea.

```
function sortbyfifth() {
  var arr = [['', 121, '', 24603.0, 'Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019', 'sunday', ''], ['', 131, '', 62531.0, 'Sat Jul 13 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019', 'monday', ''], ['', 141, '', 33210.0, 'Thu Jul 11 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019', 'tuesday', ''], ['', 142, '', '-', '', '', 'Yes'], ['', 143, '', '', 'Sat Jul 13 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019', 'monday', '']];
  
  arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    var va = 0;
    var vb = 0;
    //var ta = Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date(a[4]));//not required
    //var tb = Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date(b[4]));//not required
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date(a[4])) === '[object Date]') {
      va = new Date(a[4]).valueOf();
      if (isNaN(va)) {
        va = 10000000000000000;//normally I'd go with zero here but the extremely large number forces undefined to the bottom of sort ascending.  If you reverse the order you'll want to change this to zero. 
      }
    } else {
      va = 10000000000000000;
    }
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date(b[4])) == '[object Date]') {
      vb = new Date(b[4]).valueOf();
      if (isNaN(vb)) {
        vb = 10000000000000000;
      }
    } else {
      vb = 10000000000000000;
    }
    let tc = Number(va) - Number(vb);
    return va - vb;
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/],/g,"],\n"));//I added the replace so that it would be easier to read the output of the console log
}
```

Execution log

```
4:11:38 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:11:39 PM  Info    [["",141,"",33210,"Thu Jul 11 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019","tuesday",""],
["",121,"",24603,"Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019","sunday",""],
["",131,"",62531,"Sat Jul 13 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019","monday",""],
["",143,"","","Sat Jul 13 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019","monday",""],
["",142,"","-","","","Yes"]]
4:11:39 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

You could spend a little more time in the logic area to determine if both a and be are undefined or just a or just b.  If just a then then return +1 if just b then return -1 if  both a and b then return a 0.  Otherwise return a - b.